# Tinymce AutoResize issue

Tags: javascript, editor, tinymce, textarea, autoresize

I'm using tinymce 3.5 with the autoresize plugin. The plugin works great for me while the user is adding content, but afterwards I'm serializing this content in order to allow for later editing of it. The issue is that after deserializing the content the autoresize plugin won't trigger. I tried executing 
`tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceAutoResize');`
in the onInit, onPostRender and so on callbacks but it is to no avail - my content gets cropped to initial height of the text area. After typing in some text the issue disappears. Is there a way that I'm not awared of to manually call the autoresize plugin. Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I've tried  init_instance_callback with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to manually call the Resizing in the [`init_instance_callback`](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:init_instance_callback)?

You can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12382834/1062304).